# Closest neighbor to value selected at random from list?

Tags: python, list, random, list-comprehension

I have a list where I am selecting a number at random. I now want to choose the closest integer in the list to the number I have selected. Below is what i have so far:

```
from random import choice

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
r = choice(a)
```

So for example if r = 9, the nearest neighbor would be 8. For r=7 it could be either 6 or 8. Which of the two closest isn't particularly important, so long as it is a neighboring value.

Comment: If r = 9, is it possible to choose 7?  If Yes, what's the probability of choosing 7 and 9, respctively?

Comment: what if the list has duplicate elements

Comment: The list will always be from 0-9. I'm trying to choose the closest so for r=9 it would be 8, for r=5 it could be 4 or 6

Comment: you can find the index of `r` then you can select the neighbour

Comment: Thank you I will try that @komatiraju032

Comment: If the list is always 0-9 and in that order that's important info that you should put in your question, not just in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use numpy

```
from random import choice
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
r = choice(a)

neighs = a[abs(a - r) == 1]

print(r, neighs)
# 7 , [6 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method that sorts the array and searches for the closest neighbour. As you mention that the choice between the two closest isn't particularly important, so long as it is a neighbouring value i.e. for r=7 it could be either 6 or 8. This method chooses the smallest of the two closest neighbour i.e. for r=7 it selects 6 not 8.

```
def getclosest(targetVal, sample):
    dif=100; cand=0;
    for x in sample:
        if (abs(x - targetVal) < dif)& (x!=targetVal):
            dif = abs(x - targetVal);
            cand = x;
    return cand;
```